# Google chart, annotations and label issues

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts, google-visualization

I'm generating a graph using google chart, however I have several problems.

First: Currently an annotation is displayed in the second series in which it shows the place in the ranking. However, if there is more space in the second series (gray background) the text is moved lower or disappears completely. I would like the annotation ("place in the ranking") to be always on one line and in case of lack of space, it overlaps both series (blue and gray).

Second: in the case of labels (january, february, march etc.) when the label is too long or consists of several words is dotted, and I would like it to move to the next line.

How to solve this problem ? Thank you in advance for your answer.

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Genre', 'Zrealizowane', {role: 'annotation'}, 'Niezrealizowane', {role: 'annotation'}],
        ['january', 10, '', 90, '7th place in the ranking'],
        ['february', 16, '', 84, '7th place in the ranking'],
        ['march', 16, '', 84, '12th place in the ranking'],
        ['april', 10, '', 90, '7th place in the ranking'],
        ['may', 16, '', 84, '12th place in the ranking'],
        ['june', 100, '', 9, '7th place in the ranking'],
        ['juli', 16, '', 84, '12th place in the ranking'],
        ['august', 81, '', 90, '2nd place in the ranking']
    ]);

    var options = {
        chartArea: {width: size, height: '90%', right: 20},
        legend: {position: 'top', maxLines: 2},
        bar: {groupWidth: '46px'},
        isStacked: 'percent',
        hAxis: {
            minValue: 0,
            ticks: [0, .25, .5, .75, 1]
        },
        series: {
            0: {color: '#0077c4'},
            1: {color: '#f2f2f2'}
        }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_progress'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
```

[image]